# Point to a page when there is no results

Tags: posts

Is it possible to point to a specific page when there are no results ?

For example i have this on my search.form , i am asking if there is a way to change the get_template_part and make it point to a specific page.

Tried to

```
get_permalink( get_page_by_title( 'name-of-the-page-here' ) );
```

But didn't work. Else:

```
get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'none' );
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Using "get_template_part()" has very specific formatting requirements.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_part/

To alter your example:

```
get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'page' );
```

would work, if your .php file was located at "template-parts/content-page.php"

Comment: Thanks for answering. But i have the my php file inside template-parts/content-page.php, although my question is if i can replace "get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'page' );" with something like "get_permalink( get_page_by_title( 'name-of-the-page-here' ) );".

Comment: To make it more clear i want the the results working as it is if it founds what you typed but point to another custom url if there no results to show.

Comment: If I'm reading you correctly, it sounds like you want to redirect to a different PAGE on the site if there are no search results. I'm assuming you're using an IF-ELSE statement of some sort. If that is the case, you can just use something like `wp_redirect( 'https://example.com/another/page' );` in the second part of your ELSE...